# reference & pointers confusing parts(declarations and their types)

Tags: c++, pointers, types, reference

I'm studying pointer and reference parts and having very hard time to study them.
I think I understand now some simple usage of reference and pointers in the function, but there is something I cannot totally understand.

Here are some variable declarations:

```
int a = 1;
float b = 2;
int* p = &a;
string s = "Hello";
vector<int*> values = {p};
```

What will be the types of the following expressions?

```
&a
&b
p
&p
&s
&(s.at(1))
values.at(0)
&(values.at(0))
&values
```

I have no idea what their types exactly are, but I tried it myself.

```
&a : pointer to int
&b : pointer float
 p : pointer to int
&p : pointer to pointer to int
&s : pointer to string
&(s.at(1)) : pointer to string
values.at(0) : pointer to int
&(values.at(0)) : pointer to pointer to int
&values : pointer to pointer to int
```

and one more problem >
write the following variable declarations:
a) A pointer to a string
b) A reference to a float
c) An array of pointers-to-ints.
d) A pointer to a pointer to bool
e) A reference to a pointer to an int

and my answers are:

```
a: string* s = "Hello"

b: float& f = g;

c: int n =1;
   int*x =&n;
   int arr[] = {*x};

d: bool y = true;
   bool* x = &y;
   bool** qq = &x;

e: int a = 1;
   int* x = &a;
   int& z = *x;
```

I'm not sure about my answers. Please help these confusing parts.

Comment: `int a;` `a` is an **int**. `int *pa;` `pa` is **pointer to an int**. Now when `a` will store a integer value, `pa` will store an address since pointers are nothing but address. Therefore, `pa = &a;` i.e `pa` stores address of `a`. Note: `pa and &a` are same i.e both are pointers to an int.

Comment: Your answers to *c* and *e* are wrong. `int arr[]` declares an array of integers, not and array of pointer to integers and similarly `int& z` is a reference to an integer, not a reference to a pointer. (and `string* s = "Hello"` shouldn't compile, you can't initialize `string*` this way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a `std::string` is a complex object that contains a char array but it is definitely not a char array. And a `std::vector<int>` is also a complex object that contains an array of ints.

That means that for the first part some of your tries are wrong:

```
&(s.at(1)) : pointer to string               WRONG: pointer to char
values.at(0) : pointer to int                OK
&(values.at(0)) : pointer to pointer to int  OK
&values : pointer to pointer to int          WRONG: pointer to `vector<int>`
```

For the second part, as a string is not a char array, you cannot initialize a pointer to string with a litteral char array

```
string *s = "hello";   WRONG syntax error
```

You must first create a string and then create a pointer to it

```
string s = "hello";   OK std::string initialized from a const char *
string *ps = &s;      OK pointer to std::string
```

c is wrong too `int arr[]` declares an array of int. You must write:

```
int *arr[] = { x };  OK array of 1 pointers initialized from x which is a pointer to int
```

For e, `int&z = *x;` declares a reference to int initialized as a ref to a. To get a ref to a pointer, you must write:

```
int *&z = x;   OK ref to a pointer to int initialized as a ref to x
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, really helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:

If the expression `e` has type `T`, the type of `&e` is `pointer to T`; `T*`.
Consider the types of the expressions `s.at(1)` and `values` more carefully.

Part 2:

c: `int arr[]` is not "array of pointers-to-ints", it's "array of `int`".
An array of `T` is `T arr[]`; an array of `int*` is `int* arr[]`.

```
int n = 1;
int* arr[] = {&n};
```

e: `int& z` is not "reference to a pointer to an `int`", it's "reference to `int`".
A reference to `T` is `T&`; a reference to `int*` is `int*&`.

```
int a = 1;
int* x = &a;
int*& z = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the exact type of an expression and if you can use Boost, it provides a great functionality.

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define TYPE(x) std::cout << "decltype(" << #x << ") == " << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>().pretty_name() << std::endl

int main()
{
    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

    int a;
    TYPE(a);

    int * p = &a;
    TYPE(p);
    TYPE(&p);

    std::vector<int*> values {p};
    TYPE(values.at(0));
    TYPE(&(values.at(0)));
    TYPE(&values);
}
```

If you can't use Boost, you can still deliberately create a template error to force the compiler to show you the type of expressions (from a talk of Scott Meyers, a great expert of C++).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
    class TD;

template <typename T>
void function(T & param)
{
    TD<T> templateType;
    TD<decltype(param)> paramType;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    function(a);

    int * p = &a;
    function(p);
    function(&p);

    std::vector<int*> values {p};
    function(&values);
}
```

> c) An array of pointers-to-ints

You created an array of `int` containing a single value, the value to wish the pointer refers to. As said previously, you need a `int* []` array.

Answer (score 0):

> &(values.at(0)) : pointer to pointer to int  OK

Why &(values.at(0)) is a pointer ?

Pointer is variable that contains address in memory
Pointer has its type

```
    unsigned long ip = 0xC0A80A01;  // 192.168.10.1
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&ip;
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", p[3], p[2], p[1], p[0]); 
    // Result: 192.168.10.1
```

I think it is only takes address of variable.

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a; 
&a is not a pointer
p is a pointer
```

Is it?

and
int &refVar = a;
refVar is reference